# Relationship example

Tags: ios, core-data

Can someone help me with a simple core data relationship example?  I've looked at all the tutorials and still can't find what I need.

Example:

One to many relationship:

Entity: State
state
relationship:courses

Entity: GolfCourses
coursename
relationship:statename

so State<-->>GolfCourses

If I have an existing State, how would I add coursename records?

```
 GolfCourses *newCourse = (GolfCourses *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectforEntityName:@"GolfCourses"
inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

newCourse.coursename = courseTextField.text;
```

Then do I do:

```
statename= SOMETHING?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to either create new or fetch an existing `State` and then assign it to `newCourse.statename`.

You can create new `State` with:

```
 State *newState = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectforEntityName:@"State" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];];
```

and assign:

```
newCourse.statename = newState;
```

Fetching takes a couple more lines, but you should be able to do it after reading [Fetching Managed Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdFetching.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002484-SW1).

Comment: Looks like exactly what I need!  But if I am assigning to an existing State, after I do the predicate fetch, what would the assignment code look like?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out!  Many thanks for your assistance!!  You really helped me out of a bind!